# How to Restrict API call from subdomains

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I know we can restrict API call from IP filtering. But for MS Dynamics CRM online all the instances has same IP address but subdomains are different. Is there any was we can allow API call only from one instance.

Comment: It is impossible to restrict api call based on domain name.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any was we can allow API call only from one instance.

**It is impossible to restrict api call based on domain name.** As you have said, you could use  [`ip-filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#RestrictCallerIPs) policy filters (allows/denies) calls from specific IP addresses and/or address ranges.

```
<ip-filter action="allow">
    <address>address</address>
</ip-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible if calls to APIM are done from browser at client side. Is that the case? If so, use APIM policy to check Referrer header and return error if it doesn't match the one you want.